# Publish ASP.NET MVC 3 RC to Windows Azure

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to deploy my ASP.NET MVC 3 RC to Windows Azure.I've added all references for MVC 3 and Razor specific dll's and set for them "Copy to Local" property. So should be pretty straight forward. However when i've done publish i've got a pretty strange error. Exception show me that application can't find partial view (the first which is loading in my master template. The same error i've got if i am trying to run application under Development Fabric locally.

This view (partial view) is definitely exist, because when i run application under usual way by Visual Studio Dev Server Cassini or on IIS it works like a dream without any errors.

So looks like this is something specific for Azure.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that the Build Action of all of your Razor files is set to `Content` and not `None` (settable in the Properties pane, which you can access via <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd>